# Grid search for optimization problem

Tags: optimization, python

Suppose you wanted to solve the following optimization problem:
$$\inf_{a \geq 0}\sup_{b \geq 0}\dfrac{(a^2 + 1)(a + b)}{2a + b} + \dfrac{b}{a + b} - ab,$$
where $a, b$ are scalars. How would you use a Python program to perform grid search for this optimization problem? I'm having quite a bit of trouble with it because I am not quite sure how to discretize and upper-bound my search space. Thank you.

Comment: For any $a>0,$ $\lim_{b\rightarrow \infty} f(a,b) =\infty,$ where $f(a,b)$ is the objective expression. (The first two terms are nonnegative and the third blasts off to infinity linearly.) So the supremum is finite only for $a=0,$ in which case $f(0, b)=2$ for all $b>0$ (and is undefined for $b=0$). Are you sure this is the correct expression of the objective?

Comment: I made a serious error - should have had a negative towards the end. Thank you! @prubin

Comment: Are you committed to using grid search as opposed to something like bisection search, or a gradient based search?

Comment: Any method would be helpful. The goal for me is to solve the optimization problem.

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}$
Define $$f(b\vert a)=\dfrac{(a^2 + 1)(a + b)}{2a + b} + \dfrac{b}{a + b} - ab$$ and $$g(a) = \argmax_{b \ge 0} f(b\vert a).$$ For any given value of $a,$ we will evaluate $g(a)$ numerically by doing a line search for the max of $f(b\vert a)$ in the $b$ direction. To get the optimal value of $a,$ we do a line search for the min of $g(a).$

How you do the line searches is up to you. Since $f$ is differentiable, you could use bisection search when evaluating $g(a)$ and, say, [golden section search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden-section_search) when minimizing $g().$ It might be easier from a coding standpoint to do golden section search along both axes. There are other line search algorithms, but I'm pretty comfortable with golden section.

To do a search for the maximum of $f$ given a value of $a,$ I would start with $b = 0$ and evaluate $f(1, a), f(2, a), f(4,a), f(8,a) \dots$ until I had a big enough value $b_0$ of $b$ such that one of the points in the interval $[0, b_0]$ had a bigger value of $f()$ than either 0 or $b_0$ had, telling me there was a maximizer (or at least a local maximizer) somewhere in the interval $[0, b_0].$ That would be my starting interval for GS search.

Similarly, when search for the minimizer of $g,$ I would look at $g(0), g(1), g(2), g(4), g(8)\dots$ until I saw the value of $g$ turn back upwards, giving me the starting interval for GS search on the $a$ dimension.

I'll add two disclaimers. First, GS search finds a global optimizer when the function in question is unimodal (only turns from decreasing to increasing or increasing to decreasing, whichever is relevant, once). Otherwise you are only guaranteed to find a local optimizer. Second, the business of finding the initial search interval by taking longer and longer steps until you see the function values change direction won't work as described if the function is increasing/decreasing toward an asymptotic value. If I saw a bunch of function values that pretty much stopped changing (changes smaller than numerical tolerance, or smaller than the number of decimal places I was using), I would just stop there and define the first instance of the asymptotic value as the upper endpoint of my search interval.

Edit: I'm not a Python user, but R has multiple library routines for optimizing functions of a single variable. My guess is that Python does as well.